# Celery task queuing

Tags: flask, celery, scheduled-tasks

I have created a flask application and it consist of 2 celery tasks.

***Task 1: Generate a file through a process***

***Task 2: Email the generated file***

Normally task one needs more time compared to task 2. I want to execute task 1 and then task 2. But the problem is both start to execute at the same time inside celery.

How can I resolve this issue.

```
@celery.task(name='celery_example.process')
def process(a,b,c,d,e,f):
    command='rnx2rtkp -p '+a+' -f '+b+' -m '+c+' -n -o oout.pos '+d+' '+e+' '+f
    os.system(command)
    return 'Successfully created POS file'

@celery.task(name='celery_example.emailfile')
def emailfile(recipientemail):  
    email_user = ''
    email_password = ''
    subject = 'subject'
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['From'] = email_user
    msg['To'] = recipientemail
    msg['Subject'] = subject
    body = 'This is your Post-Processed position file'
    msg.attach(MIMEText(body,'plain'))
    filename='oout.pos'
    attachment  =open(filename,'rb')
    part = MIMEBase('application','octet-stream')
    part.set_payload((attachment).read())
    encoders.encode_base64(part)
    part.add_header('Content-Disposition',"attachment; filename= "+filename)
    msg.attach(part)
    text = msg.as_string()
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
    server.starttls()
    server.login(email_user,email_password)
    server.sendmail(email_user,recipientemail,text)
    server.quit()
    return 'Email has been successfully sent'
```

This is the app.route

```
@app.route('/pp.php', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def pp():
    pp = My1Form()
    target = os.path.join(APP_ROOT)
    print(target)

    for fileBase in request.files.getlist("fileBase"):
        print(fileBase)
        filename = fileBase.filename
        destination = "/".join([target, filename])
        print(destination)
        fileBase.save(destination)

    for fileObsRover in request.files.getlist("fileObsRover"):
        print(fileObsRover)
        filename = fileObsRover.filename
        destination = "/".join([target, filename])
        print(destination)
        fileObsRover.save(destination)

    for fileNavRover in request.files.getlist("fileNavRover"):
        print(fileNavRover)
        filename = fileNavRover.filename
        destination = "/".join([target, filename])
        print(destination)
        fileNavRover.save(destination)

        a=fileObsRover.filename
        b=fileBase.filename
        c=fileNavRover.filename
        elevation=pp.ema.data
        Freq=pp.frq.data
        posMode=pp.pmode.data
        emailAdd=pp.email.data

        process.delay(posMode,Freq,elevation,a,b,c)
        emailfile.delay(emailAdd)

        return render_template('results.html', email=pp.email.data, Name=pp.Name.data, ema=elevation, frq=Freq, pmode=posMode, fileBase=a)
    return render_template('pp.php', pp=pp)
```

Comment: Reduce your example code by removing all the print statements we don't care about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it currently stands your code does the following:

```
# schedule process to run asynchronously
process.delay(posMode,Freq,elevation,a,b,c)

# schedule emailfile to run asynchronously
emailfile.delay(emailAdd)
```

Both of these will immediately be picked up by workers and executed.  You have provided **nothing to inform `celery` that `emailfile` should wait until `processfile` is complete**.

Instead you should:

- alter the signature of `emailfile` to include another parameter that will be the output of a successful `processfile` call; then
- call `processfile` using `link`.

For example:

```
deferred = processfile.apply_async(
    (posMode,Freq,elevation,a,b,c), 
    link=emailfile.s()) 
deferred.get()
```

An alternative to using `link`, but semantically identical in this case, would be to use a [`chain`](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.html#celery.chain).

Comment: According to you solution I have added this code for app.route`res=process.apply_async((posMode,Freq,elevation,a,b,c), link=emailfile.s(emailAdd))`. But this gives me following error message in celery.  **emailfile takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)',)**

Comment: Now its working I have changed the code that I have mentioned previously like this `process.apply_async((posMode,Freq,elevation,a,b,c,emailAdd), link=emailfile.s())` and changed the return value of the **process** as resipient email. Thanks for the help @donkopotamus

Comment: @Richiedlon yes, as was already noted in the answer, you would need to *alter the signature of  `emailfile` to include ... the output of a `processfile` call*